# web-service calls in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loader

I am building an app in android, where first activity does an **Rest api** call and shows the result on the screen.

To do the web-service call,i can use **asynctask** or **loader** or **Handlers** . Services won't be good option as it's not a long-running operation and it is tied to the activity life cycle.

I can use libraries like volley and robospice. But, before using the libraries, i would like to know the efficient approach.

What to use **aysncTask**? If it's not recommended because of issues like restarting when screen orientation. Then, when it should be used?

Or Loaders would be the best approach, as it takes cares of all issues?

I am new to android.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the libraries. Volley and Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) are the main candidates.

Comment: Also, do not use AsyncTask as it is a very outdated code and gives bad results. The general approach is to just have all those stuff outside the activity and have a way for it to "connect" to the data source. Here is a very good video on the topic if you want to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Comment: Thank you @Budius , thankx for the video. After, going though some docs, i think loaders would be an efficient way, for this task. or loaders with volley?

Answer (score 0):

Read about Google [SyncFramework](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

With it you can use Volley for data fetch and in your fragment/activity you can use Cursor with Loaders for data refresh/fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
void IncomeJsonData(String json) {

    try {
        //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        {

            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Income income = new Income();
            income.setId_id(obj.getInt("Id_id"));
            income.setIn_addamount(obj.getDouble("In_addamount"));
            income.setIn_amtdate(obj.getString("In_amtdate"));
            income.setIn_amtcat(obj.getString("In_amtcat"));
            income.setIn_mode(obj.getString("In_mode"));
            income.setIn_description(obj.getString("In_description"));
            income.setIn_active(obj.getBoolean("In_active"));


            Log.e("BAVO", income.toString());

            income_list.add(income);

        }
        Log.e("C", income_list.toString());
        custom_class = new Custom_class(ViewIncomeActivity.this, income_list);
        lst_income.setAdapter(custom_class);
        //lst_income.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Show_Error", ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
class ConsumeIncomeWebservice extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String jsonString = new String();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;

        try {
            String url1 = "http://192.168.43.126/Android_webservices/Pocket_expence.svc/GetAllIncome";
            URI uri = new URI(url1);
            url = new URL(uri.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //urlConnection.getResponseCode("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection.connect();

            Log.e("Error_error", "Hal Ne bhai");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();

            jsonString = sb.toString();
            Log.d("", "doInBackground: " + jsonString);

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        }
        return jsonString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.e("Post_Exe", "PostExe");
        if (s != null && !s.equals("")) {
            IncomeJsonData(s);
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON_amit", "NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some context as to why the code you've provided solves the OP's issue.